Trying to highlight words in image using ocr
When I try to highlight words in chosen image it fails saying there's no  words for the text(Tessereact.js) and I tried many things to make it mark words in the image after the ocr but still fails to, this is the last code edit after failing many times, I want it to be like tesseract.js website demo where it can mark where is words after performing ocr
script.js
const langSelect = document.getElementById('langSelect');
const fileInput = document.getElementById('fileInput');
const ocrButton = document.getElementById('ocrButton');
const extractSelect = document.getElementById('extractSelect');
const extractButton = document.getElementById('extractButton');
const imageContainer = document.getElementById('imageContainer');
const textOutput = document.getElementById('textOutput');
var input_overlay = document.getElementById('highlightCanvas')
var ioctx = input_overlay.getContext('2d')
let extractedText = '';

fileInput.addEventListener('change', function () {
  const file = fileInput.files[0];
  imageContainer.src = URL.createObjectURL(file);
});

async function performOCR() {
  const lang = langSelect.value;

  if (lang && fileInput.files.length > 0) {
    const file = fileInput.files[0];
    ocrButton.disabled = true;
    ocrButton.classList.add('disabled');
    textOutput.innerHTML = '<div class="loading"><span class="loader animate" aria-label="Processing your request"></span><span>Loading...</span></div>';

    try {
      const { createWorker } = Tesseract;
      let tessdata;

      if (lang === "eng") {
        tessdata = 'eng.traineddata';
      }

      const worker = await createWorker(lang, 1,{
        workerPath: "./dist/worker.min.js",
        logger: m => console.log(m),
        tessdata: tessdata
      });

      const { data: { text } } = await worker.recognize(file);

      if (text) {
        result(text);
        await worker.terminate();
      } else {
        textOutput.innerText = 'No text found.';
        extractedText = '';
        await worker.terminate();
      }

      imageContainer.innerHTML = `<img src="${URL.createObjectURL(file)}" alt="Uploaded Image">`;
    } catch (error) {
      textOutput.innerText = 'Error: OCR failed.';
      textOutput.classList.add('error');
      console.log(error);
      extractedText = '';
    }

    ocrButton.disabled = false;
    ocrButton.classList.remove('disabled');
  } else {
    textOutput.innerText = 'Please select a language and an image file.';
  }
}

function extractText() {
  const fileType = extractSelect.value;

  if (fileType && extractedText) {
    const blob = new Blob([extractedText], {
      type: `text/${fileType}`
    });

    const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    const link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = url;
    link.download = `extracted_text.${fileType}`;
    link.click();
  } else {
    textOutput.innerText = 'Please select a file type and perform OCR first.';
  }
}
function result(res){
    // octx.clearRect(0, 0, output.width, output.height)
    // octx.textAlign = 'left'

    console.log('result was:', res)
    // output_overlay.style.display = 'none'
    // output_text.innerHTML = res.text
    textOutput.innerText = res.text;
    extractedText = res.text;
    res.words.forEach(function(w){
        var b = w.bbox;

        ioctx.strokeWidth = 2

        ioctx.strokeStyle = 'red'
        ioctx.strokeRect(b.x0, b.y0, b.x1-b.x0, b.y1-b.y0)
        ioctx.beginPath()
        ioctx.moveTo(w.baseline.x0, w.baseline.y0)
        ioctx.lineTo(w.baseline.x1, w.baseline.y1)
        ioctx.strokeStyle = 'green'
        ioctx.stroke()


        // octx.font = '20px Times';
        // octx.font = 20 * (b.x1 - b.x0) / octx.measureText(w.text).width + "px Times";
        // octx.fillText(w.text, b.x0, w.baseline.y0);
    })
}


index.html:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>OCR Reader</title>
    <script src="./dist/dist-tesseract.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./7.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="center">
        <select id="langSelect">
            <option value="eng">English</option>
        </select>
        <input type="file" accept="image/png, image/jpeg" id="fileInput">
        <button onclick="performOCR()" id="ocrButton">Perform OCR</button>
        
        <div id="content">
                <div>
                <canvas id="highlightCanvas"></canvas>

                    <img id="imageContainer"><div id="textOutput" class="output-box"></div>
                </div>
        <select id="extractSelect">
            <option value="">Select File Type</option>
            <option value="txt">Text File (.txt)</option>
            <option value="docx">Word Document (.docx)</option>
        </select>
        <button onclick="extractText()" id="extractButton">Extract Text</button>
    </div>
    


    <script src="./dist/worker.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./script.js"></script>

</body>
</html>


tried many things and even libraries to make it mark the words using ocr in the chosen image and still doesn't work
